# Is profile considered as an object?

Tags: profile, object

I'm asking because someone mentioned that a new field was added to our profile table, but when I checked, I couldn't find "Profile" in the object manager...

Any idea how a field was added in profile 'object' ?

Comment: Profiles are metadata not an object. Do they mean access to a field was added to the profile? Or alternatively does your organisation have either a custom object named Profile or refer to something else (like User) as a profile?

Comment: New fields get added to Profile as a result of certain feature enablement

Comment: Hi Callum, basically my data guy who has the back end access of database (we synced the data apparently) notify us that there's a field name "PermissionsSalesforceIQInbox" was added in our profile table, I am just trying to find out what that field is and how/who added it. I am very sure there's no custom object named Profile in our environment. Many thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Profiles, permission sets, and permission set groups grant access to an object and the object's fields. In the Salesforce API, the back end objects are as follows (2nd picture).

Although a Salesforce Admin can use either profiles, permission sets, or permission set groups to configure access, the Permission Set back end object contains information on all three.

How to use SOQL to query Object and Field Permissions in a Profile.

- STEP 1 - Every profile is associated with a Permission Set. Find the Id of the PermissionSet associated with the
  profile. `SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'`
- STEP 2 - Query on FieldPermissions Object to get the field access details with the PermissionSet Id (ParentId) from step 1. `SELECT Id,SobjectType,Field, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND ParentId = '0PS4w0000011cEyGAI' LIMIT 10`

[image]

[image]

Resources -

https://www.apexhours.com/security-in-salesforce/

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/salesforce-tip-3-object-field-permissions-louis-duc-nguyen/

Comment: Thank you for the info Saroj, I will take a look and try to understand lol. Am still very new with Salesforce